# Malicious? Code in my JS file that wasn't there previously

Tags: javascript, security, code-injection

I don't know too much about web security but I found a piece of code in a javascript file of mine yesterday that would not have been added by me or anyone else with access to my website. 
Nothing bad seems to have been happening on the site so I wouldn't have worried that much except that I have been consistently told by Google Adwords that I have malware on my website. Every time I ask them to investigate however, neither they nor google search console can find anything.

The piece of code in question was this something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://synchronize.exsads.com/click.js">
```

The only reason I found it was because it gave me an error in the dev console because the file wasn't able to be loaded.

I have no idea how the code got there. I've been trying to read up on code injections and XSS attacks but i don't really understand it and it seems like that has more to do with sending malicious code back to a server instead of actually changing the code within files. (please correct me if I'm wrong)

Is there a specific security vulnerability that would allow someone to access the code on my website, and if so, what steps do I have to take to prevent that? (Details or easy to understand resources please, much appreciated!)

Comment: there are many ways this could happen. we can't help you track down why it happened without knowing more about your site.

Comment: "exsads"... almost certainly advertising. but we're not here to identify code for you, or figure out how you server (may have) gotten compromised.

Comment: well to put it simply yes and no. It's hard to tell if you don't provide us any background

Comment: There are many vulnerabilities that would allow some to access the code on your website.  Countless.

Answer (score 0):

That JS insert ads on your site.

Search manually for a extrange PHP file (i'll asume php), they generate extra HTML and insert some ads on your site.

*EDIT*

Ok, it's not a CMS. Change your FTP password and access to CPanel or PLESK.

Follow this steps: enter over FTP to the files on your hosting, look for a obvious with a extrange name .php file or .js, that file is the corrupted one.

Other solution: download all site over FTP and scan with a good antivirus.

Comment: I'd be happy to provide more details, just let me know what you want to know. The website is www.bestattorney.com. 
Hosting is on inmotionhosting on a dedicated server - not sure what you want to know about that.